# Find minimum number of steps to a goal without estimator for how close intermediate steps are to the goal

Tags: algorithms, search

I've been trying to find a good way of solving the following problem, but I'm not sure how to even frame it. I think there might be relatively well-known solutions I'm not familiar with, since I don't have much knowledge of algorithms. How could I approach this?

#### Example problem:

There's a known begin-state *A* and known end-state *B*. There is a known sequence of (a large amount of) points that lead from *A* to *B*. I would like to find a minimum/small number of points that will describe the path from *A* to *B*. I can test for any sequence of points whether it reaches *B* using that, but if it doesn't I don't have an estimation of how close it is to getting to *B*. I'm basically trying to find the points that are essential for getting to *B*, but I won't know whether they are sufficient until the path is complete.

#### What I found so far:

The problem appears a bit similar to polyline simplification,
and one option would be the [Ramer Douglas Peucker algorithm](http://karthaus.nl/rdp/). I don't think it will work well for my problem though, because I don't necessarily want to follow the non-essential points on the path(which may be outliers or unnecessary circumventions).

The solution I came up with myself sounds a bit like greedy & binary search:

1. Pick middle point *C* between *A* and *B* and discard all points between *A* and *C*.
2. Check whether this path reaches *B*.
3. If *B* cannot be reached, there is an essential point between *A* and *C* we missed, so pick middle point *D* between *A* and *C* and test path with points between *A* and *D* discarded.
   If *B* *can* be reached, we might be able to discard point *C* and some subsequent points, so pick *D* between *C* and *B* and discard points until *D*.
4. Do this until identified a point *D* furthest from *A* that still leads to *B* if all the points between *A* and *D* are discarded.
5. Start this search over, now starting from *D* instead of *A* until all essential points have been identified

#### Other thoughts:

I might be able to give a "similarity" estimation for end-state *B1* that is reached from some point *C* in comparison to the targeted end-state *B*. Would that provide a wider variety of applicable algorithms?

Comment: Sounds like there would be a large number of DAG-shortest-path algorithms that would suit.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like in can be described in terms of finding the shortest path between two points on a graph; if you are able to rephrase it in those terms, [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is probably what you're looking for.

You say you have no way of estimating the path length, but if you can provide a lower bound on it that varies to some degree you may be able to reduce the amount of effort required to perform your search using [A* search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: There's other variants of A* that can be more efficient depending on the exact usage, such as A* JPS.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have *n* steps going from *A* to *B*. Now you construct a vector **p** containing *n* 0s or 1s where the i-th 0 indicates that the i-th step is left out and a 1 indicates the step is done.

You want to find a **p** with minimal norm (sum of elements) under the condition that function *f(**p**)*=1.

*f(**p**)* is defined as 1 if the path containing of the steps where **p** is 1 is getting you from *A* to *B*. Function *f* is given by you. Either it is only 1 and 0 (path doesn't reach B) or you may also have a similarity estimate (how close the path reaches to B) which corresponds to *f* taking for example all possible values between 0 and 1 where close to 1 means "almost reaching B".

Now, you did not specify further knowledge about *f*. Does it have many local optima or is it continuous (if it is the similarity measure)?

If nothing is known about *f* I guess the only choice is starting with **p** of minimal norm and working its way upwards (so only one step, then all combinations of only two steps, ...) until you hit the first time a solution and stop. This might end up in NP running time.

If *f* is continuous this kind of reminds me on [Langrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) which might be used for minimizing the norm of **p** while keeping the path described by **p** a solution.